# jquery remote passing 2 post data

Tags: jquery

I have a form that will ask for a certain date, pen number and cycle number. If there's already an entry for that certain date, cycle number and pen number. it should return false. I have used jquery remote validation to do this. My problem is how can I make 2 post data that will passed to my controller?

Here is my code:

```
   pen_no: {
  required: true,
  remote:{
  url: "admin/val_pen_no_dr",
  type: "post",
  data:{
  cycle_no_trans:function(){
  return $("#cycle_no_trans").val();
  }
  }         
    }    
  },
```

The thing is I can only make the cycle_no_trans into a post data. I want to add the date field in my post data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {
   cycle_no_trans: $("#cycle_no_trans").val(),
   date: (new Date).toDateString()
}
```

`data` accepts either a query string or a JavaScript object; you can put as many arguments as you like and even nest them.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the date field is also a user input. When I tried your code, firebug shows that cycle_no_trans has an empty post data. The jquery remote documentation says that it should look like this when passing a value: 
cycle_no_trans:function(){
      return $("#cycle_no_trans").val();
      }
Do you have any idea how can I solve my problem?